# NET VIEW behaves differently when used with Process.Start()

Tags: c#, cmd

I use `net.exe` in my program to view all computers in a workgroup.

The code is as follows:

```
   var net = new Process();

   net.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
   net.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   net.StartInfo.Arguments = @"VIEW /DOMAIN:my-workgroup";
   net.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   net.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   net.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   net.Start();
```

The command works fine when I execute in a shell, but when I use the shown code, the command returns `the device is not connected`.

I also tried running the program as administrator, that makes no difference.

The domain name specified **is actually a workgroup**.

For `net.exe` running in the shell specifying a workgroup works fine.

Furthermore the code also works when I try a `net view` for a different domain. So there must be some difference in the environment when I run the command from the shell or with `Process.Start()`.

What would be the reasons for the command to behave differently in the shell and with `Process.Start()`?

Comment: When I take that exact code and run it in my scratch program, it runs `net` just fine. Are you sure that it's *this* code generating the error?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes I am absolutely positive.

Comment: Run it with just plain /DOMAIN without the name so you'll at least get a list of valid domain names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve what you're looking for, but this works for me;

You need to hook into the capture the output to bring it to the console

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var net = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", @"view /domain:domain")
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput =  true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            },


        };
        net.OutputDataReceived += WriteToConsole;
        net.ErrorDataReceived += WriteToConsole;
        net.Start();
        net.BeginOutputReadLine();

        net.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void WriteToConsole(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your code, unfortunately I got the same result as with my code

Comment: strange, sorry not sure what else to suggest